# CodeIgniter: How do I fix "Trying to get property of non-object" and "Array to string conversion" errors and the reason for them to come?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In 'new_payment' table and the 'new_reservation' table, each row (payment) has a res_id (PK in new_reservation and a reser, FK in new_payment, CASCADE, CASCADE). I have to fill 3 input boxes.

Total Bill: [    ]

Previously Paid: [    ]

Due Amount: [    ]

When user enters a room number and submit, controller calls 'search_by_room_number' model and the model then,

1. Returns 'total' from new_reservation table
2. Returns 'res_id' from new_reservation table into variable called $res_id
3. With that $res_id, I look for previously 'paid_amount' in new_payment table
4. ...and 'due_amount' in new_payment table

**But unexpectedly, following errors comes in:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: models/payments_model.php
Line Number: 16

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: models/payments_model.php
Line Number: 18

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: models/payments_model.php
Line Number: 16

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: models/payments_model.php
Line Number: 18
```

**Model:**

```
function search_by_room_number($room_number) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT total FROM new_reservation WHERE room_number = '$room_number' AND payment_status = 'Pending' LIMIT 1"); // Line 16
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row->total; // Line 18

    $res_id='';

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT res_id FROM new_reservation WHERE room_number = '$room_number' AND payment_status = 'Pending' LIMIT 1");
    $row = $query->row();
    $res_id = $row->res_id;

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT paid_amount FROM new_payment WHERE res_id = '$res_id' LIMIT 1");
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row->paid_amount;

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT due_amount FROM new_payment WHERE res_id = '$res_id' LIMIT 1");
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row->due_amount;

}
```

**Controller:**

```
function search_room_number() {
        $popRoomNumbers = $this->input->post('room_number');

        $totalBill['total'] = $this->payments_model->search_by_room_number($popRoomNumbers);
        $previouslyPaid['paid_amount'] = $this->payments_model->search_by_room_number($popRoomNumbers);
        $dueAmount['due_amount'] = $this->payments_model->search_by_room_number($popRoomNumbers);

        $tmpFormData=array_merge($totalBill, $previouslyPaid, $dueAmount);
    $this->load->view('/main/new_payment', $tmpFormData);
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php $attr = array(
                'name'  =>  'totalBill',
                'id'    =>  'totalBill',
                'class' =>  'span2',
                'readonly'=>'true',
                'value' =>  $total
            );
echo form_input($attr);
?>            

<?php $attr = array(
                'name'  =>  'previouslyPaid',
                'id'    =>  'previouslyPaid',
                'class' =>  'span2',
                'readonly'=>'true',
                'value' =>  $paid_amount
            );
echo form_input($attr);
?> 

<?php $attr = array(
                'name'  =>  'dueAmount',
                'id'    =>  'dueAmount',
                'class' =>  'span2',
                'readonly'=>'true',
                'value' =>  $due_amount
            );
echo form_input($attr);
?>
```

Comment: what does $res_id = $row->res_id; in your model return? is it an array by any chance> if so can you give an example of it's outcome?

Comment: why you are doing 2 queries for fetching 2 fields of the same row? maybe there is no result for your query! You should handle this exception.

Comment: $room_number is a integer or array check it and also check the query error using $this->db->_error_message()

Comment: I debugged it myself and was able to make figure it out. Anyway, thanks everyone! (Updated new code as an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try it like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT total, res_id FROM new_reservation WHERE room_number = '".$this->db->escape($room_number)."' AND payment_status = 'Pending' LIMIT 1");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $row = $query->row();
    $total = $row->total;
    $res_id = $row->res_id;

} else {
    throw new Exception("No records found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able try something different myself too. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I went through it again myself line by line and finally able to provide more efficient code.

```
function viewTotalBill($room_number) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT total FROM new_reservation WHERE room_number='$room_number' AND payment_status='Pending' LIMIT 1");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        return $row->total;
        }
    }   
    //else throw new Exception("No records found"); 
}

function viewPreviouslyPaidAmount($room_number) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT res_id FROM new_reservation WHERE room_number='$room_number' AND payment_status='Pending' LIMIT 1");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT paid_amount FROM new_payment WHERE res_id = '$row->res_id' LIMIT 1");
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            return $row->paid_amount;
            }
        }
    }
    //else throw new Exception("No records found");
}


function viewDueAmount($room_number) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT res_id FROM new_reservation WHERE room_number='$room_number' AND payment_status='Pending' LIMIT 1");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT due_amount FROM new_payment WHERE res_id = '$row->res_id' LIMIT 1");
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            return $row->due_amount;
            }
        }
    }
    //else throw new Exception("No records found");
}
```